# I have released Kyogre, can it be re-obtained?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I have released Kyogre by accident. Is there any way to encounter and capture this Pokémon again?

Comment: Is this Alpha Sapphire?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the only way to obtain Kyogre again is to either soft reset (which isn't an option as I assume you've saved it since the battle), start over again completely, or to trade one through the GTS.

**EDIT:** If you've saved it before the release, you could also load that Game Save.

Comment: The last save should be before the release, not per se the battle

Comment: @Mathias711 That is a very good point. I have added that into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have caught any legendary pokémon in your game, they will never reappear even if you trade them away or release them. The only way to get another is to either start your game from the beginning or be traded one.

Answer (score -1):

If reset is not an option, you can participate on events, get legendary pokémon and bargain it to get Kyogre back.